# Calling methods on a parent window from iframe fails in Opera

Tags: javascript, opera, cross-domain-policy

In one of my pages I have an iframe which is loaded from a different subdomain than of the main page.
In both documents I set the *document.domain* to be the same, then I try to call a method from the iframe on the parent page, something like:

```
window.parent.page.doit()
```

This works well in most browsers (IE, firefox, chrome, safari) but fails in opera with the following error message:

> Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Security error: attempted to read
>   protected variable: page

From what I managed to find on this, it seems like Opera have tighter security than the rest of the browsers. Have anyone came across this issue? Any ideas how to fix it or any workarounds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set document.domain to the second level domain on both pages, i.e.

**maindomain.com**

```
document.domain = "maindomain.com";
```

**subdomain.maindomain.com**

```
document.domain = "maindomain.com";
```

Comment: I wrote that *In both documents I set the document.domain to be the same*, otherwise it would not have worked in the other browsers as well.

Comment: i create testpage here: http://testplayground.com/xdm/ ,works fine in opera 11.61 (mac os). is it works in your opera?

Comment: Yeah, that works in my opera, I'm not sure why I had the problems I described, I changed some code to fix another problem and the error just disappeared. I'm not sure what triggered it, since I clearly did change the domains of both documents. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some versions of Opera (around 11.60 I think?) cache the security info of a page or something like that, causing security errors that only disappeared after clearing cache and restarting. It sucks for debugging but at least your visitors typically won't have this problem..

Comment: The problem disappeared somehow, I have no idea how, but I can say for sure that clearing the cache (history, cookies, what not) had no effect on this issue, not even restarting (both browser and machine).

Comment: Wow. The only other thing I can think of would be timing problems. The document.domain = ... line should be as early as possible in the page, and not be inside onload or other event handlers..

Comment: Nope, I checked to make sure that it's not the case, I used _alert_ (since it blocks) so that I'll know what happens when. the _document.domain_ assignments happened before there was any communication between frames.

Comment: very weird. I'm actually sorry the problem has disappeared, we should have analyzed it.. :-p

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware that you're on the opera team. It is a shame that I have no much useful info on how to reproduce this issue, what I can tell you is that I was not using a recent version. What I have now is *Version: 11.52, Build: 1100, Platform: Linux* (id: "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686; U; en) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.52").